# Does object overhead matter when emulating a 6502 processor in Java? (using wrappers instead of primitive types)

Tags: java, performance, memory, emulation, wrapper

I'm programming an emulator in Java (currently working on the 6502 processor), and I'm planning to use my own wrappers for some primitive types, simply because it enables me to do some things easier. The problem is, I'm planning to emulate a complete NES console, and the CPU has access to 65536 bytes of memory. A primitive byte is 1 byte, a wrapper is AT LEAST 8 bytes. Creating an array of 65536 bytes (primitive) vs 65536 Bytes (wrapper) would cause at LEAST 8 times the amount of memory usage, not accounting for registers and whatnot. Not only that, but I can only assume that using objects instead of primitive types will be slower. What I'm wondering now is, since modern processors have gigs of RAM anyway, is it bad to use at least 8 times as much memory just to make it a bit easier on myself (and probably decrease the size of the emulator a little)? Or should I keep it efficient and just use primitive types?

Comment: Actually a reference to a `Byte` is at least, and still *typically*, 4 bytes due to OOP compression.

Comment: Yes, perhaps to the standard Java Byte wrapper class, but I'm using my own. I suspect that this means it will still be 8 bytes.

Comment: No, a reference is a reference... this is a low-level JVM optimization. It stores Ordinary Object Pointers in 4 bytes instead of 8. Anyway, whichever object you use, you'll cache all 256 possible values and the footprint will be almost entirely independent of the size of your objects.

Comment: The question is tagged with Java, so just a comment: There is a Scala feature which allows you to extend primitive types without any performance penalty. So you don't "lose" the normal operators like "+", it keeps the code clean (no wrapper required), and you can add you own "operators".

Comment: Why at all you consider using wrapped bytes as option? What benefits do you expect?

Comment: Some kind of pass-by-reference for primitive types mostly, and also signed/unsigned conversion methods in value itself instead of having int tempUValue = (register & 0xFF) scattered everywhere, and a couple more reasons. Might not be good reasons for you, but as someone who has just started messing around with processors, it is confusing as hell, doing it the way I'm doing it right now with Java's "different" take on primitive types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the memory footprint of the JVM itself will *dwarf* whatever memory you allocate for your 6502 emulation.

As is quoted so often for these sort of questions,

> premature optimisation is the root of all evil

and I would get your implementation correct first, and only then identify any optimisations you can/should make.

Comment: What does this "drawf" mean? I assume it has something to do with compressing/shrinking something, but what do you mean by it?

Comment: It's plain English language :) "A dwarfs B" == "B looks like a dwarf compared to A".

Comment: Ah, in that manner. I've rarely ever heard the word dwarf used as a verb anyway, so I was confused.

Answer (score 1):

Compared to the speed of this CPU your current machine is so much faster, that you really don't need to worry about performance.  You would have probably go out of your way and write exceptionally bad code to get such an issue. :)